# WCHAN=unix_s in Linux

Tags: linux, process, fork

What does WCHAN=unix_s it indicate?

I have a process that forks many processes. The main process is stuck in unix_s and all the child processes are in poll_s.

I also have a couple of processes that is stuck in futex_ that is semaphores. But what does it mean exactly?

also sk_str.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly indicates that the actual WCHAN value didn't fit in the `ps` output column, thus got truncated.
You can set the column width when calling `ps`, eg.

```
ps ax -O wchan:22
```